# Nodejs Express - methodOverride not working for multipart/form-data

Tags: javascript, forms, node.js, express, x-http-method-override

I've noticed that if I submit a form with `enctype="multipart/form-data"` that has a hidden _method input set to `PUT` the methodOverride function will not fire, resulting in a `404 POST` for that route.

The set up:

```
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencode());
...
app.use(express.methodOverride());
app.use(express.router());

app.put('/update', express.multipart(), function(req, res) { ... });
```

if i change *put* to *post* in the router everything works just fine. Also put and delete work in other routes that do not have `enctype="multipart/form-data"` sent to them.

I tried changing the order of the middleware but no luck with that.

Any help would be highly appreciated, since googling this issue resulted in nothing!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For [`methodOverride()`](http://www.senchalabs.org/connect/methodOverride.html) to be able to use the value of `_method`, it needs [`req.body`](http://expressjs.com/api.html#req.body) to already have been defined by 1 of the 3 *body parsers* -- `json()`, `urlencoded()`, and `multipart()`.

```
app.use(express.multipart());
app.use(express.methodOverride());
```

If you want to use `multipart()` with `methodOverride()` for select routes, you can use an [`app.all()` route](http://expressjs.com/api.html#app.all) with both middleware and call [`next('route')`](http://expressjs.com/api.html#app.VERB) so it continues to the intended route.

```
app.all('/update',
    express.multipart(),
    express.methodOverride(),
    function (req, res, next) { next('route'); }
);

app.put('/update', function (req, res) {
    // ...
});
```

Comment: @Skatebail It should be fine to use it multiple times. If `_method` is available to both, they should just set the same value to `req.method`. Unless somehow your app manages to set 2 values for `_method`.

Comment: Thank You very much, both for your help and time, it is working!